# How to retrieve the name of type T? I'm always getting "RuntimeType"

Tags: c#, generics

How do I retrieve the name of the type T that was used to initialize RuleViewModelBase? Right now I'm getting "RuntimeType"

```
public abstract class RuleViewModelBase<T> : IRuleViewModel where T : RuleEntity, new()
    {
        public bool Editable
        {
            set
            {
                _editable = value;
                if (Condition != null)
                {
                    Condition.Editable = value;
                }
                if (Content != null)
                {
                    Content.Editable = value;
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return _editable;
            }
        }
        private bool _editable;
        private string _groupsJson;
        private List<RuleGroupJM> _groups;
        public string RuleType { get { 
            return typeof(T).GetType().Name; } 
        }
        public RuleContentVm Content { set; get; }
        public RuleConditionVm Condition { set; get; }
        public virtual void SaveToEntity(T rule)
        {

        }
        public RuleEntity ConvertToEntity()
        {
            T rule = new T();
            rule = (T)this.Content.SaveToEntity(rule);
            rule = (T)this.Condition.SaveToEntity(rule);
            SaveToEntity(rule);
            return rule;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `typeof(T)` yields the type of `T`. Calling `GetType` on that gives the type of the value returned by `typeof`. This is obviously _not_ what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want:

```
typeof(T).Name
```

Instead of:

```
typeof(T).GetType().Name
```

The code you had was getting the name of the type that corresponds to the instance of `Type` that refers to your class.  i.e.  effectively you were doing `typeof(Type)` (or more specifically, `typeof(RuntimeType)`) and getting the name of that.